# Convert eigen vector to QString for display

Tags: c++, qt, eigen, qtgui, qtcore

What is the easiest way to print a vector from the `Eigen` library in a Qt interface?

Is there an easy way to convert the vector to a QString so that I can use `setText()`?

Or is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: Cannot you use QVectorXD? Is it some performance critical stuff? In any case, please give some input and expected output examples. What format would you like to get it printed in?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I did some computations using Eigen, so therefore I have everything in such a vector, but if I could somehow cleverly transfer it into the format that you suggest that would be fine. Performance is not a big issue. I would want the entries of the vector to be printed underneath eachother. Since there are not many entries in the vector, I thought of using Qlabels. But if there is a more clever way to print them all at once I'd prefer that.

Comment: Use a QtextOStream and operator<< maybe?

Comment: @MarcGlisse: That you will not use with setText() without additional work.

Comment: @LaszloPapp ok, I am not familiar with Qt, but since Eigen provides an operator<< it would be sad if Qt had no way to use that.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: but that is for stream, not strings, but if operator<< is overloaded the way OP wants, you could pass your QString as the constructor, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the following for an N dimension vector:

```
QString myString;
for (int i = 0; i < svector; ++i)
    myString.append(QString(vector[i]) + "\n");
myLabel.setText(myString);
```